# (Android Studio) How to debug through my code only?

Tags: java, debugging, android-studio, step-into

When I try to debug through my code in Android (using Step Into, F7 command), the debugger takes me through all system classes, which I do not want.

For example, when I place a breakpoint at the 2nd line below (i.e. "startActivity(ourIntent);"), instead of going into my Activity (i.e. "myclass), the execution point goes into Activity.java > Instrumentation.java, etc... all system classes.

I dont want that. I only want to step through my code that I have written.

What is a way to achieve this?

```
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, "com.practice.gamesbook.myclass");
        startActivity(ourIntent);
```

"Add new Pattern" option under "Debugger" > "Stepping" is disabled

[image]

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Go to `Android Studio > Preferences > Debugger > Stepping` then in the bottom click the plus arrow with the question mark that says `Add Pattern`. Type `android.*` and hit OK and then Apply.

Comment: thanks - but i see that in my envt, the "Add New Pattern" button is disabled, cant click on it. Any idea why that may be?

Comment: @user1406716 I've found that sometimes when using the search feature within Settings (in your example above, you've typed "Debugger") that some options in the pane on the right are disabled. Clear the filter search ("debugger" text), manually navigate Debugger->Stepping, then try. The read-only status of the controls should clear.

Comment: With pattern, android.* you might also include com.android.*

Comment: where is that "Android Studio > Preferences" option? I see "File, Edit, View, Navigate, Code, Analyze, Refactor, Build, Run, Tools, VCS, Window, Help"

Comment: I see it now(file..settings). I've also added  besides android.*   also, dalvik.*   and com.android.*    just checking the package headers of classes it was going through any time I saw it going through classes I didn't write/didn't want it to, and using patterns of those ones.

Comment: In AS 2.0 debug options are under Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Stepping

Comment: is there any way to pop debugger in case of a condition?

Comment: @barlop File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Stepping

Answer (score 24):

For the latest version of android studios

1. Go to `File->Setting` and search for `Stepping`
2. click on `+?` sign on the right side
3. add the following 4 patterns one by one

   `com.android.*`

   `android.*`

   `com.androidx.*`

   `androidx.*`

Comment: I have added all these and even *.java.   And I still run into java files that I didn't write.   Is there anything I missed?   I use kotlin.

Comment: Hello, I think It should work for Kotlin, not sure why It didn't work for you. please try adding  `.*\.java` (i think it will skip all the java files). just a wild guess.

Comment: For Kotlin, I also added `kotlinx.*`.  I find it very odd to have to do this manually - I already have "Do not step into Kotlin runtime library implementation classes selected"...

Answer (score 17):

In Android Studio 2.0 select File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Stepping.  Then click the "Add Pattern" [image] button on the right.  Type android.* (or whatever pattern you want to exclude) and click "OK" twice.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Adam Johns's answer for ignoring the Android libraries, you can use the "Step Over" button (F8) to step over a method call the details of which you're not interested in, such as from any other library you import.

Answer (score 8):

Use f9 (Resume Program).
This will Resume your Program and stop only to the next Break Point.

Comment: band aid solution when Android Studio needs a critical surgery.

Answer (score 3):

Shift-F11 to step out of the method helps too.

Answer (score 3):

In Android 2.3.1 Go to **Android Studio > Preferences > Debugger > Stepping** then in the bottom click the plus arrow icon which has dot,star and question mark which is Add Pattern. Type android.* and com.android.* and click OK and  Apply.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Add Custom Pattern

Android Studio 3.x.x

**Android Studio > File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Debugger > Stepping**

### 2. Step Over(F8)