# Android Studio. How to debug through my code only?

Tags: android, debugging

I mean how to avoid stepping through system methods.
There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486163/android-studio-how-to-debug-through-my-code-only)

It is written:

Go to Android Studio > Preferences > Debugger > Stepping then in the bottom click the plus arrow with the question mark that says Add Pattern. Type android.* and hit OK and then Apply.

But I can't find preferences in Android Studio.
There is settings. 
There are debugger settings in there.
But there is no stepping settings.
Can someone kindly point me to stepping settings?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what version of Android Studio you have, but you can always use the Search field in the top-left corner in the Settings/Preferences window, that will filter the options for you; just search for Stepping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it in Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Stepping

And find "Do not step into the classes".

Android studio 1.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Simply Just use 'f9' (Resume Program).

This will Resume your program Normally and will stop only if there is a Break Point.

Hope this helps you.